# Mass conservation in spherical coordinate

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

See four velocity $u^\alpha = \gamma(1,\beta,0,0)$ in a spherical coordinates $(ct,r,\theta,\phi)$,

The mass conservation is 
\begin{equation}
\nabla_\mu(\rho u^\mu) = 0
\end{equation}

Then how it can be expressed as something like (I'm not sure if it is correct expression)

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial(\rho r^2 \gamma\beta)}{\partial r} = 0
\end{equation}

Comment: When you say 'in spherical coordinates', do you mean that it is flat space with spherical coords (metric $ds^2=-dt^2+dr^2+r^2d\theta^2 + r^2sin^2(\theta)d\phi^2$)? The covariant divergence depends on the metric.

Comment: @jacob1729 you're right, the length is exactly what you proposed. My question is also how does the covariant divergence depends on the metric?

Comment: See eg [the first answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/213466/gradient-divergence-and-curl-with-covariant-derivatives) or the early chapters of most GR books have a section on tensor analysis that derives these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now find the answer!

\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu} =  
\begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & r^2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & r^2\sin^2\theta
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

According to Section 4.5 in [Blau 2018 GR lecture notes](http://www.blau.itp.unibe.ch/Lecturenotes.html), the covariant divergence can be written compactly as

\begin{equation}
\nabla_\mu V^\mu = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\partial_\mu(\sqrt{g}V^\mu)
\end{equation}

So the conservation of the mass should be like below
$$
\nabla_\mu(\rho u^\mu) = 0
\\
\frac{\partial(\rho\gamma)}{\partial ct} + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial(r^2\rho u_r)}{\partial r} = 0
\\
\frac{1}{r^2c}\partial_t(r^2\rho\gamma) + \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r(r^2\rho\gamma\beta) = 0
\\
\frac{1}{r^2c}\partial_t(r^2\rho\gamma) + \frac{1}{r^2}\beta\partial_r(r^2\rho\gamma) + \rho\gamma\partial_r\beta = 0
\\
\frac{1}{r^2ct}\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}(r^2\rho\gamma) + \rho\gamma\partial_r\beta = 0
$$

Comment: I think you dropped a $\partial_t$ in that last line.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thank you! it should be a total derivation sign